# Is the method of finding a slant asymptote correct?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, asymptotics

I understand the idea behind finding a slant asymptote: we asume, that at an infinite distance of argument, function should be equal to some line function, so to check that we take a line function expression that is $kx+b$, set it equal to inspecting function expression, and find a limit of it, where argument goes to infinity.

In sources I read, it is done in illegal way: inspecting function is set to be equal to just $kx$, from where $k$ is obtaining as $k=\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$, and after $k$ is obtained, it just passed to complete line expression $kx+b=f(x)$ as a constant, and now $b$ is obtaining in the same way: $b=\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)-kx$.

Actually, I can't surely state why it is wrong, but, probably, because $k$ in $kx + b$ is just an another variable?

For example, we obviously can't solve $3x+y=1$, by just removing $y$ for a while, as $3x=1,\space x=\dfrac{1}{3}$ and then put it back, getting $\dfrac{3}{3}+y=1, \space y = 0$... And when I ended typing it understand, that $x=1/3$ and $y=0$ are solution for the equation above...

I am totally confused, can someone explain where my algebra knowledges are wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is better to be precise with the definitions. We say that $f(x)$ has a slant asympote for $x \to +\infty$ if, for some $m, q \in \mathbb R$, with $m\neq 0$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} [f(x)-mx -q] = 0.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
It is not always easy to understand if $m$ and $q$ exist and to find them, by directly using \eqref{1}.

The idea behind the procedure you mention is to notice that if \eqref{1} is true, then
$$\lim_{x\to + \infty} \frac{f(x)}x = m.\tag{2}\label{2}$$
So \eqref{2} is a **necessary condition** for \eqref{1} to hold true. Therefore you can first verify if \eqref{2} holds true for some $m\neq 0$. And *then* use this value of $m$ in \eqref{1} and verify whether the limit
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}[f(x)-mx]$$
exists and it is finite.

---

EDIT. **Proof that \eqref{2} follows from \eqref{1}.**

If \eqref{1} is true, then
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} [f(x) - mx] = q.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)-mx}{x} = 0,$$
which can be written as
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left[\frac{f(x)}x - m\right] =0,$$
which in turn is equivalent to \eqref{2}.

---

EXAMPLE 1.

In some cases it is easy to find $m$ and $q$ directly by inspecting the function. For example
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2-2x}{x+1}$$
can be written as
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &=&\frac{x^2+x-3x}{x+1}\\
&=& \frac{x(x+1)-3x-3+3}{x+1} =\\
&=& \frac{x(x+1)-3(x+1)+3}{x+1} = \\
&=& x-3 + \frac{3}{x+1},
\end{eqnarray}
which shows that \eqref{1} is true for $m=1$ and $q=-3$.

EXAMPLE 2.

There are cases, though, in which using \eqref{2} is very convenient, in order to find the equation of the slant asymptote, because it splits the problem in two parts. Take
$$f(x) = (x-3) e^{\frac{x-1}{x-2}}.$$
First observe that when $x\to \infty$ the exponent converges. This hints at the possiblity that \eqref{2} might be true for some $m\neq 0$. In fact we have
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}x = e$$
(exercise for you). We still do not know if $f$ has a slant asyptote, though, since \eqref{2} is a necessary (not sufficient!) condition.
But now we can see if there is a $q$ for which \eqref{1} holds true. I.e. we check the limit
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}[f(x)-ex].$$
I leave it as an exercise for you to find that the limit in fact exists and is equal to $-2e$, so that we have a slant asympote with equation
$$y=e(x-2).$$

Comment: 1) Where $(1)$ comes from? We assume, that at $x→+∞$, given $f(x)$ should equal line, i.e. $mx+q$, so the difference between $f(x)$ and $mx+q$ at infinity should be zero? 2) If first assumption is true, would it be also correct, to get $-mx-q$ out of the limit and place it in the right side of the equation?

Comment: 3) And mainly - I still do not understand, why $q$ disapears in $(2)$, probably I do not know something about limits. As I understand, limit of polynomial equals to limits of monomials, comined by corresponding operations, so $(1)$ can be represented as $\lim_{x\to + \infty} (f(x)-mx) + \lim_{x\to + \infty}(-q)=0$. Since second limit does not contain variable, that limit intended for, it will just equal expression, so it'll be $\lim_{x\to + \infty} (f(x)-xm)-q=0$, and according to this, the necessary condition for $(1)$ to be true, i.e. $(2)$ should be $\lim_{x\to + \infty}\dfrac{f(x)-q}{x}=m$

Comment: 1) What you state is an "informal" definition. The formal version is precisely (1). And you should refer to that one in order to handle everything correctly.

Comment: 2) A limit of a function is a number, not another function. So you **cannot** move $mx+q$ outside the limit and then at the other side of the equality.

Comment: 3) You should first concentrate on the definition of limit, I guess. Your assertions are confusing. For example, it is not true that $\lim_{x\to \infty} (-q)=0$. The limit is in fact $-q$.

Comment: $q$ does not *disappear*. The point is: **if** (1) is true, **then** (2) is true. Start working on this statement, I would suggest. Divide the expression in brackets in (1) by $x$ and compute the limit.

Comment: 3) "*it is not true that $lim x→∞(−q)=0$*" - I did not write that, I wrote exactly, that it equals to $-q$

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv sorry, I misunderstood. I cannot quite follow what you wrote in that comment.

Comment: "*The point is: if (1) is true, then (2) is true*", can You please provide the proof? Because, as I wrote, You just illegaly bring the $-q$ out of the equation, or I missing someting

Comment: "*I cannot quite follow what you wrote in that comment*" - I provided not actually complete, but a proof, that (2) in Your post should be $\lim_{x\to + \infty} \frac{f(x)-q}x = m$

Comment: @sahgasdvsadgv added to proof. Note the first step. I guess that's the one that bothers you. Why? 

Of course also your limit is equal to $m$ since $q/x\to 0$. The advantage of $(2)$ is that it only depends on **one** unknown rather than two!

Comment: In Your proof, $q$ again just disapers from the right side of the equation, becoming a zero, and You do not explain why, but it seems I understand now, why, but You probably have a mistake then: if (1) to divide both side by x, zero at right side remain zero, but for limit, as I understand, coefficient can get into it, as well, as out of it, so there will be $\lim_{x \to +\infty} [\dfrac{f(x)-mx -q}{x}] = 0$, that is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to +\infty} [\dfrac{f(x)-mx}{x}] -\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{q}{x} = 0$, and the second limit is equal to zero, because of x in denominator.

Comment: The only problem, that I doubt, that variable as coefficient can move inside\outside of the limit, instead of constant as a coefficient, so if it true, I still do not understand, how it works

Comment: Check by the definition of limit that if $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to x_0} [f(x)-L] = 0 $, and viceversa. That you can do because $L$ is constant. A completely different matter is when there are terms depending on the variable $x$ (in this case).  Those cannot obviously be moved outside the limit. Added some examples in the text. Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, let me some time to get into it, maybe I indeed missing something

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can separate out the two parts is because of what the limit does to the constant $b$.  Suppose that $\lim{x \rightarrow \infty} = kx+b$.
Then,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{kx+b}{x} = k+\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{b}{x}.$$

The second limit is zero, so that only $k$ is left.  Now, notice that
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (f(x)-kx) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} ((kx+b)-kx) = b.$$

Comment: Sorry, what does $lim\space x→∞=kx+b$ mean?

Comment: Please double check.  Each of my limit statements should be correct.

Comment: @Doug There is in fact a mistake in the second line of your text, as pointed out already.

Comment: @dfnu and Doug, I am sorry, I actually passed limits in school, and in the anlysis book, I currently read, I have not reached this topic yet, so I can't state that thre is a mistake, but as I remember, after limit sign there should be an expression, and after the expression there (may) be an equality sign with another expression. But equality sign right after limit seems to have no sense